# chart.js load new pie data on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

I'm using chart.js and trying to get the pie chart to update the chart data when a user clicks something.
In this case: `<span class="click" id="one" title="one">One</span>`

It is updating properly and a new chart is showing up but the new chart seems to be twice as big.  What am I doing wrong and is there a better way to do this?

See:
http://jsfiddle.net/aU8VL/2/

Answer (score 0):

Your chart did not become big or has some bug in it, its because you added different values on the `onClick` and also `onload` has different value. To check your work if its the same, you need to provide same value on both events.

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aU8VL/3/).

Comment: Not sure I understand you completely. Your jsfiddle is buggy just like my original.

Comment: i didn't change anything from your code, only the value to make the both pie same.

Comment: Let me clarify, I want a different chart (with different values) to load onClick.